# rewrite rule .htaccess file parameter as sub domain

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to make my URL parameter a subdomain. For example I have this URL

```
mysite.com/list.php?url=google.com
```

And I want it as

```
google.com.mysite.com
```

I have tried many solutions from the Internet but nothing worked for me.

The latest I found and tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.mysite.com [L,R=301]
```